# What careers offer steeply increased income for increased hours?

Tags: careers

[Generally](http://www.inc.com/jessica-stillman/why-working-more-than-40-hours-a-week-is-useless.html) after working for 40 hours or so, increased work has diminishing marginal returns on productivity due to fatigue.

Presumably, this translates to increased work having diminishing marginal returns on an employee's income.

However, I do not know if some careers are exceptions to this. If there are careers that require an individual to understand a very large amount of frequently changing material, then I can conceive that increased productivity due to being more knowledgeable could outweigh the decreased productivity due to fatigue.

When I say "steeply increased income," I mean ones whose diminishing marginal returns either increase, remain constant, or decrease significantly less than they do in other jobs.

However, a cursory search revealed no such jobs.

Comment: This question is unclear.  Are you talking from the employer's perspective (productivity/additional time unit) or the employees (pay/additional time unit)?  Once you reach the point where you get OT as an employee you see a sharp increase in marginal return and then again where you pass the threshold from 1.5x OT to 2x OT.

Comment: "If there are careers that require an individual to understand a very large amount of frequently changing material..." then these positions are likely to be paid on a salary basis anyway, so maybe the real question is whether working significantly more than 40 hours per week on average is going to be a net positive benefit to you.

Comment: You are confusing income with work performed. Unless you are being paid per sneaker/smartphone/t-shirt your question simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I worked in the oil business and often construction companies will offer overtime at regular rate or even a premium if the project demands it and it is a paid project.  They also tend to offer a lower base to cover for slack times.

Comment: @Myles Edited. I meant from the employees perspective. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere What don't you understand? I am not currently seeking a new job.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yeah, that sentence was gibberish. Edited. Anyways, are you sure productivity is irrelevant to pay? Wouldn't low productivity lead to being less likely to be promoted and more likely to be fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many blue collar jobs are like that. The bottleneck in productivity in many of them is not a mental fatigue one, but a physical one. When I was planting pine for example there is a short window of time to get all the trees in the ground ready for spraying (which also has a small window). So the fitter the worker was the more he could plant. Some treat it as a 9 to five job and make roughly the same every week. Others like me are greedy and we worked sunup to sundown 7 days and made more than most white collar workers.

Productivity didn't decrease and the extra income from the two extra days I often made an extra 50% on top of what I'd made the rest of the week.

So I know from experience that a small gang of five, fit, motivated planters, is more productive than an average gang of 20 working normal hours.

Factory work is much the same, things are set up so you basically service a line like a robot, you can do this as long as they'll let you (within reason) and steadily make more money, in fact overtime is 1.5 your rate and weekends 2 or 3 times your rate, so it can make a big difference to your income.